# 'johny.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Form1_Load'

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have this error:

> Error    1   'johny.Form1' does not contain a definition for 'Form1_Load'
>   and no extension method 'Form1_Load' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'johny.Form1' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

This is my code from the form's designer:

```
    // 
    // Form1
    // 
    this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
    this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
    this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(456, 411);
    this.Controls.Add(this.l6);
    this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
    this.Name = "Form1";
    this.Text = "Form1";
    this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
    this.ResumeLayout(false);
    this.PerformLayout();
```

The error is from this line:

```
 this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is telling you that you don't have a `Form1_Load` method in your `Form1` class, and you are trying to use one.

Delete that line if you don't need to do any initialization when the form first loads, or ensure you do have one (that conforms to the signature of the `EventHandler` delegate).

Answer (score 4):

That means that there is no `Form1_Load` method anywhere inside `Form1`. To fix that, you either need to delete that event handler generated code or in  `Form1`, add a `Form1_Load` method, for example:

```
 this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load); // <----- REMOVE THIS
```

OR:

```
public partial class Form1
{
...
Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
// Do whatever
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
```

or implement method:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //your code
}
```